# How to gracefully close React Native Application for Android

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to React Native Application. I am using below code to close the application on clicking of a button.

```
BackHandler.exitApp();
return false;
```

But application is not properly ended and still is in Taskbar. So when I try to open the application again, `componentWillMount` never executes.

I am using below version of React Native.

- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.55.4

Any help or advice on how to cleanly close React Native Application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google and Apple won't advice to force quit an application so you should avoid doing that so for better user experience.

If you need to recall a function when your app comes back from background you can use [react-native's Appstate API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html). With Appstate you can listen for app states (active, background and inactive) and run your desired function.

> `AppState` can tell you if the app is in the foreground or background,
>   and notify you when the state changes.

Below is a sample for requesting data and refreshing the list on every time screen comes back foreground.

**Sample**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, AppState } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  }
  requestItems = () => {
    fetch('someurl').then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJSON) => this.setState({data: responseJSON.data}))
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.requestItems()
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this.requestItems);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
     AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.requestItems);
  }
  renderItem = ({item}) => <Text>{item.text}</Text>
  render() {
    if (this.state.data.lenght === 0) return <Text>{'Loading'}</Text>
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList data={this.state.data} renderItem={this.renderItem} keyExtractor={(item) => item.id} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```